# How to fetch only top-most level div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('#container').find('div')` will also include those inner divs.

How to fetch only the 3 top-level divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [children([expr])](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children#expr) function to do this.

Something like

```
$("#container").children("div")
```

Comment: "Something like .." is most important:)

Answer (score 1):

Select only the direct descendants with the [parent > child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child) selector:

```
$('#container > div')
```

Or the [Traversing/children](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children) function:

```
$('#container').children('div')
```

Comment: What if the id is unknown(container),but only has the jQuery object of $('#container')?A little hard to understand maybe.

Comment: how is `$("#container > div")` harder to understand than `$("#container").children("div")`..? I must say I would prefer the CSS selector any time.