# How to select children elements but only one level

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html code.

```
<div data-value="1">

    <div data-items="bind">
        <div data-item="Black" />
        <div data-item="Orange" />
    </div>

    <div data-types="bind">
        <div data-type="Books" />
        <div data-type="Mobiles" />
    </div>

    <button>button 1</button>
    <input type='text'/>

</div>

<div data-value="2">

    <div data-items="bind">
        <div data-item="Black" />
        <div data-item="Orange" />
    </div>

    <div data-types="bind">
        <div data-type="Gifts" />
        <div data-type="Cards" />
    </div>

    <button>button 1</button>

</div>
```

I have two parent divs that contains data-value "1" and "2".

**first:**

> I want children of div that contains **data-value="1"**. The output
>   should be 4 children 2 div, 1 button, 1 input

**second:**

> I want children of div that contains **data-value="2"**. The output
>   should be 3 children 2 div, 1 button

How is it possible using jQuery's.

Comment: `$('div[data-value="2"]').children();`

Comment: here's the docs http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Have a look at [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2487747/218196) and [How to fetch only topest level div with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1345401/218196) and combine those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div[data-value='1']").children();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/FTawW/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/FTawW/1/) is working.

Answer (score 3):

Direct Descendant Selector

```
$("div[data-value='1'] > *");
```

Or [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method:

```
$("div[data-value='1']").children();
```

Repeat as needed.

Comment: var children = $("div[data-value='1']").children();

alert(children.length);

It returns 1  -- it should b 4

alert($(children[0]).attr('data-items'));

It returns bind

Comment: This code works. Your HTML is broken, hence the error you're noticing. `<div>` is not a self-closing tag. Fix your HTML so that your tags are properly closed, and use the code in my answer as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child element with `.children()`

```
$('div[data-value="1"]').children();
```

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function, combined with an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var $children1 = $('[data-value="1"]').children(); // children of element with data-value equal to 1

var $children2 = $('[data-value="2"]').children(); // children of element with data-value equal to 2
```