# How do I select immediate children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My CSS selector is like this:

```
.s4-ql ul.root > li > menu-item
```

I need to do some dynamic coloring on that item, so need to select the element using jQuery.

How do I do that?

```
jQuery('.s4-ql ul.root > li > menu-item')
```

doesn't seem to work because it doesn't seem to understand the `>` character or something. Can someone help me to select the `menu-item`?

Comment: yes that selector, >, is support by jquery... is "menu-item" a class name? if so use .menu-item

Comment: it's an 'a' tag link. jQuery('.s4-ql ul.root > li > a.menu-item') works.. weird. thanks everyone. Why downvote?

Comment: That's how you select by class, you need the period prefixing the class name

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select children elements but only one level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150809/how-to-select-children-elements-but-only-one-level)

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya typo errors are not particularly useful. Yours is a typo error (missing period).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu-item` is an class? then prefix it with an dot `.menu-item` or if its a ID then prefix it with an # `#menu-item`

Answer (score 1):

The > is supported by jQuery.  You are probably not actually selecting the right object with it.  It appears the menu-item isn't designated as a class, should it be?